# Loading very wide, shallow data in R (8M columns)

Tags: r, bigdata

I'm trying to load a file with about 8 million columns and 800 rows into R. The file is 29GB and I'm on a machine with 64GB RAM. I've tried read.table, read_delim and read_table, fread and scan. All crash or give an error like: `C stack usage 29359129 is too close to the limit.`

Here are examples of commands, all of which lead to a crash or stack error.

```
my_data <- fread("<filename.ext>" sep=" ")
my_data <- read_table("<filename.ext>", col_names=TRUE)
my_data <- scan("<filename.ext>", what = "raw")
```

I can load in a transposed version of the file just fine, but can't transpose it inside R without crashing. There are many similar questions on here and other sites about big data, but I haven't found any working solutions for extremely wide data like this.

File information:
This is a PED file produced by PLINK for genomic analysis. Details of the format can be found under "Binary PED files" on this page: *zzz.bwh.harvard.edu/plink/data.shtml*

How can I get this into R? The use of R is necessary for the particular genomic analysis I need to perform. I hope to avoid setting up a distributed storage system like Hadoop, and don't think this should be necesary since I can load the transpose of the file without trouble.

Acceptable solutions could involve loading the transpose and transposing in R, but `base::t` leads to a crash and `transposeBigData` won't run on this version of R.

Comment: One approach might be to piecewise load and transpose the file. Here might be some helpful information: 
1. https://www.r-bloggers.com/handling-large-datasets-in-r/ 2. https://rpubs.com/msundar/large_data_analysis 3. http://www.columbia.edu/~sjm2186/EPIC_R/EPIC_R_BigData.pdf

Comment: You could check out the `bigmemory` package and its big-brothers ;) Or the `ff` package